Merging arrays creates gaps betwen, the rasters
I merge many hundred rasters all in the same projection, same orientation, same resolution. The next raster should start where there last ended (no overly, zero gap).
I merge DataArrays with rioxarray's merge_arrays.
def merge(rasters: Sequence[Path], crs: int) -> DataArray):
    open_raster  = partial(open_rasterio, cache=False, crs=crs)
    return merge_arrays(list(map(open_raster, rasters)))

In a few dozen cases out of several thousands. I see a gap in the merged raster, when opening the data in QGIS. Then I overly the original files and no gap is between these.
I will try to fix it with: fillnodata.

did you reproject and then merge the data? it will probably work better if you merge and then reproject

The data was in the same projection from the start. I only had to write the EPSG-Code as it was not filled, or did I miss-understand the CRS-parameter here?

The crs parameter is the output crs of the merged raster. To set the crs, use rio.write_crs
